# How to setup Oracle ODBC for MS Access 64bit on windows

Tags: 64-bit, microsoft-access, odbc, oracle-11g

I have used more time on getting ODBC for Oracle to work than I would like to admit.

The crest is simple. Link tables from MS Access to Oracle

Everything is running 64bit. Oracle Express 11.2G, Windows 10 latest and MS Access 2019.

I have downloaded the [drivers for oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html) following the readme instructions. I can create a 64bit odbc DSN from windows but when I try the same from MS Access I get this error:

[image]

If I use use the instantclient_19_5 driver I can create a connection but I get a timeout

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Update I followed the guide suggested by @ComputerVersteher and got this error that I have seen before in one of my attempt to make this work
[image]

Comment: [Wrong Driver](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3640497)!`Microsoft ODBC driver for oracle`is only avalible for`x86`not`x64`![Use`Oracle ODBC Driver](https://manjaro.site/how-to-install-oracle-odbc-driver-on-windows-10/)

Comment: In the article you linked to I read this "Select the correct architecture of your system either 32 bit or 64 bit. In this example I am going to install the 32 bit version since I have MS Office 32 bit version." Are the article wrong?

Comment: Wrong on what? Author uses office x86,but explains x64 too.

Comment: You wrote "Microsoft ODBC driver for oracle is only available forx86 not x64" And the have drivers for both platforms

Comment: [Microsoft ODBC driver for oracle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle?view=sql-server-ver15) <>`Oracle ODBC Driver`!

Comment: Please add information as text not image! You have the requiered`Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Redistributable.(x64)`installed?

Comment: Please copy'n'paste messages or search result s are poor (check the error msg;().. Error indicates wrong bitnes.You installed x64 and used ODBC-Admin (x64)? Check https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm?ref=binfind.com/web#BABDJAFH and show Path vars and registry path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI (remove sensible infos!)

Comment: Everything is 64bit. I can create connections with the 64 bit ODBC manager. But when I use them from MS Access I get a timeout. And I think images are very usefull.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102461/discussion-between-computerversteher-and-martin-andersen).